# Получение выходного потока в переменную типа String

Tags: java

Как получить вывод в переменную типа string?

```
ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ffprobe", "C:/Downloads/1.mp4");
Process process;
process = procBuilder.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command("command1").start();


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir");
    inheritIO(p.getInputStream(), System.out);
    inheritIO(p.getErrorStream(), System.err);

}

private static void inheritIO(final InputStream src, final PrintStream dest) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(src);
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    dest.println(sc.nextLine());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Код будет читать stdout и stderr вызванной программы до ее завершения, после чего вернет строку с учетом кодировки.

```
public class ProcessOutput {
    final static String CHARSET_NAME = "cp866";

    public static String asString( InputStream is, String charsetName ) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream temp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ( (bytesRead = is.read( buffer )) > 0 ) {
            temp.write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
        }

        return temp.toString( charsetName );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder( "ping", "8.8.8.8" );
        builder.redirectErrorStream( true );

        Process ping = builder.start();

        final String string = asString( ping.getInputStream(), CHARSET_NAME );
        System.out.println( string );
    }
}
```

Вызов `asString` заблокирует выполнение программы до завершения запущенного процесса. Если такое поведение нежелательно, посмотрите [ZeroTurnaround Process Executor](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec), там есть возможность получить `Future` и взять вывод строки из него позже.

Примеры с zt-exec:

С помощью callback. Может быть полезно, когда у вас есть графический интерфейс, и вы хотите его обновить, когда процесс завершится. `CountDownLatch` нужен для демонстрации, иначе демо-программа завершается до завершения процесса. В рабочем коде нужно его убрать. Если вы используете Swing, то обращение к элементам интерфейса из callback нужно будет делать через `SwingUtils.invokeLater`.

```
public static void demo_callback() throws Exception {
    final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch( 1 ); 

    new ProcessExecutor()
        .command("ping", "8.8.8.8")
        .readOutput(true)
        .addListener( new ProcessListener() {
            @Override public void afterFinish(Process process, ProcessResult result) {
                final String output = result.getOutput().getString( CHARSET_NAME );

                System.out.println( output );

                cdl.countDown();
            };
        } )
        .start();

    System.out.println( "Тут программа делает что-то еще..." );

    cdl.await( 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS );  
}
```

С помощью Future. Полезно, если вы хотите после запуска процесса поделать в программе что-то еще, а затем получить результат работы процесса (возможно, подождав, пока он завершится), либо если вы хотите параллельно запустить несколько процессов, а потом получить все результаты.

```
public static void demo_future() throws Exception {
    List<String> pingTargets = Arrays.asList( "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4" );
    List<Future<ProcessResult>> results = new ArrayList<Future<ProcessResult>>();

    for ( String target: pingTargets ) {
        Future<ProcessResult> future = new ProcessExecutor()
            .command("ping", target)
            .readOutput(true)
            .start()
            .getFuture();

        results.add( future );
    }

    System.out.println( "Тут программа делает что-то еще..." );

    for ( Future<ProcessResult> future : results ) {
        try {
            ProcessResult result = future.get();
            System.out.println( result.getOutput().getString(CHARSET_NAME) );
        } catch ( CancellationException | ExecutionException ex ) {
            System.out.println( "Что-то пошло не так...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверил - работает. Но такое поведение нежелательно. Приведите пример использования https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec

Comment: @ВладГлушко вы в вопросе не сформулировали, какое поведение вам желательно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вызов asString заблокирует выполнение программы до завершения запущенного процесса - нежелательно.